# How to detect a platform in a Homebrew formula?

Tags: swift, linux, xcode, macos, homebrew

I have a cross-platform Swift tool that I'd like to make available both on macOS and Linux through [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

I currently have a dependency on Xcode in the formula file for it:

```rb
depends_on :xcode => "11.4"
```

This obviously doesn't work when attempting to install this formula on Linux, as Xcode is only available on macOS.

How do I detect the platform the formula is being run on and then specify a different dependency based on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Homebrew has some initiative to merge homerbew-core and linuxbrew-core for this year. And as result of that, we did introduce `on_linux` vs `on_macos` in [this PR](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/7257).

So if you are talking about formula authoring, I would recommend to use those two syntax rather than `OS.mac?` and `OS.linux?` to specify the dependencies.

Comment: Are we able to check if I'm on macos x64 or arm64 specifically? Is there sth. like `on_macos_arm64`?

Comment: You can use this `if Hardware::CPU.arm?` vs `Hardware::CPU.intel?` to check arm vs x86